# Remove all nav menu classes ( but keep useful ones... )

Tags: php, menus, customization

I'm trying to remove all menu-item classes (except for `.current-menu-{item/parent/ancestor`} and `.menu-item-has-children`)

```
function custom_nav_menu_css_class($classes) {
    $classes = preg_replace('/^((menu|page)[-_\w+]+)+/', '', $classes);
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'custom_nav_menu_css_class');
```

This almost does the job, *except* it removes `.menu-item-has-children`? Any idea what I should change, to exclude it from being removed?

(P.S. I'd rather not use a custom walker...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could work with a white-list and replace the regular expression with something more readable:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', function( $classes ) {

    $allowed = [
        'menu-item-has-children',
        'current-menu-item'
    ];

    return array_intersect( $classes, $allowed );
});
```

That would make it easier to maintain the white-list too.

Comment: Amazing function!!! There's fifty billion KB of useless classes i'll never target. Gone! Retaining active and has children, perfect! This is how WP should ship, it's so bloated....every update is worse.